# How to turn off internal Bluetooth adapter while using a USB Dongle?

Tags: wireless, usb, bluetooth

since I thought I could route the sound of my laptop (Lenovo G505s) to my BT speakers, I have run into various troubles. At this point, I know that my WIFI/BT-combi card cannot handle simultaneously handling both signals, resulting in almost non-exsistant WIFI speed. There are many approaches to this problem out there but none worked.
I thought a work around would be to buy a USB Dongle, but with blueman bluetooth manager, I only have the potion to switch BT on, now activating both adapters.
My question therefore is: can I permanently disable BT on my internal card and thus use BT and WIFI simultaneously? I couldn't even get so far as to identify the internal card, let alone deactivating it, since I am a bloody beginner to Linux and I am sorry if this is very simple but I'd appreciate any help you throw my way.

Best
Covert

**EDIT**
Thank you for your inquiry, the output is:

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet [1969:10a0] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo QCA8172 Fast Ethernet [17aa:3806]
    Kernel driver in use: alx
    Kernel modules: alx
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:3026]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 5986:0295 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please edit to add result of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb` with the bluetooth dongle plugged in

Answer (score 2):

First I would want to try enabling bluetooth coexistence in the ath9k module by

```
echo "options ath9k btcoex_enable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

Reboot and if that fails to help then...

What has worked for me in the past is to follow instructions from https://projectgus.com/2014/09/blacklisting-a-single-usb-device-from-linux/

First we

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/81-bluetooth-hci.rules
```

Then enter the following as a single line

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0cf3", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3004", ATTR{authorized}="0"
```

Then reboot

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestions, the instructions look like exactly what I was looking for. As for your first option, I already tried that exact line, following a suggestion by another (?) Jeremy over at [the Linux Mint Forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=190118#top). This was the reason I switched distros again. Sadly, the Wifi did not improve, thats why I bought the little BT dongle. I'll try both options again tonight, though. Big thanks for taking the time and for your suggestions!

Comment: Since there was no space for this addition in an edit of my original comment, I have to reply again (sorry for the mess): I just realized that the instructions from your link aim to disable a usb device while I was looking to disable the internal BT service and have solely the USB BT device up and running, thought I clarify before trying to take actions tonight just to realize I kill the wrong device. I am very sorry, but I'm not sufficiently secure in coding to make these changes on the fly myself...Thanks for your help.

Comment: The 0cf3:3004 is the internal bluetooth that is part of the Atheros wifi card you have.  The USB bluetooth dongle is the 0a12:0001 device.  That is my post on the Linux Mint forums.  I have tested the second method on my laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 and it does work, my bluetooth is also 0cf3:3004

Comment: **UPDATE** Okay, I tried option 1 again and the results are just mocking me: 1) loading websites in chromium is perfect now. 2) I have no sound in A2DP quality and Deezer doesn't load any songs, switching to Mono quality, Deezer plays everything perfectly 3) Youtube videos do not load with either A2DP or Mono quality, the loading icon takes so long that finnaly a message pops up, saying I should restart my device. I have once read this has to do with the sound card, but I do not know this. Maybe you can make sense out of this mess, but I understand if this is just too much to ask for.

Comment: I can confirm that udev black listing worked wonders on Ubuntu 18.04